# Passing a two-dimensional array to a struct (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I have a problem which includes pointers and two-dimensional arrays.

I've got a struct, which looks something like this:

```
typedef struct {
    int row;
    int col;
    int **a;
} TEST;
```

Now I want to use an object of that type for other functions. But i'm having problems passing an two-dimensional array to an object of the type.

For example i tried this:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    //Just to fill an array with some integers
    int rows = 3;
    int cols = 3;

    int a[rows][cols];

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++){
        for (int y = 0; y < cols; y++){
            a[x][y] = rand() % 10 + 1;
        }
    }

    TEST * t = (TEST *) calloc(1,sizeof(TEST));
    t->row = rows;
    t->col = cols;
    t->a = a;

    return 0;
}
```

How can I do this properly?

I'm thankful for any help.

Comment: Why `calloc`? Why pointers rather than `std::vector`?

Comment: Did you use wrong tags? Are you sure you wanted c++ and not c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to allocate a TEST object dynamically then you can do this:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    //Just to fill an array with some integers
    int rows = 3;
    int cols = 3;

    TEST* t = new TEST;
    t->row = rows;
    t->col = cols;
    t->a = new int*[rows];
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
       t->a[i] = new int[cols];    

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++){
        for (int y = 0; y < cols; y++){
            t->a[x][y] = rand() % 10 + 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you fast answer! But I still have a little problem here: If I try to compile your code, I get an error that says "cols cannot be used in a constant-expression" (I had to translate it, cause iam not using english software) for this line: t->a = new int[rows][cols];

Comment: Sorry, I wrote in the browser and did not realized it doesn't work like that. So I updated my code. Make sure you release the dynamically allocated memory properly.